# Need ideas for postdoc application re support of sponsoring institution

Tags: postdocs

I am applying for a prestigious postdoc in social sciences. I need to make a case for why the sponsoring university is particularly well suited to support me, and what unique forms of support it has to offer me. A representative of the postdoc informed the dean that the support has to go beyond what all postdocs receive. Thus I can't list "professional development" because all postdocs and grad students can access that.

The dean has offered me priority status for an internal grant of $5,000 to travel to conferences. What further types of support could the sponsoring university offer me that would advance the research, teaching, and committee work of a social science PhD?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I would really like to have your question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some ideas about what you could ask for:

- A course that is not generally available - such as a leadership program
- Support to spend a few weeks at some other institution to build a relationship?
- What do you need for your research? For example, funds for transcribing interviews, or a few months of a data analyst?

But it sounds to me like you are being asked not for a wish list, but for some thought about what is both relevant and unique about the university you are applying to. For example, is there a respected researcher in your field and you could spend some time working with that person.

Answer (score -1):

This is a fairly normal part of grant applications that are meant to fund the development of an individual rather than a program of research.

An example I am most familiar with is the NRSA set of grants in the US for PhD students and post-docs in the biomedical sciences in the US. It isn't clear to me whether you are talking about an externally funded grant or a particular funded position at the institution you are applying to.

How you answer these questions is very dependent on your individual circumstance, but you are probably best of seeking some support from people who have written or assisted in writing similar proposals in your field, successful or not. Either your current institution or the one you would like to work with may have staff that are knowledgeable, or they may be able to find you someone who previously worked there that held that grant.